# How to set up editor path in sage?

Tags: sage

I've searched everywhere and I couldn't find an answer.

I have read this in sage tutorial:

> You can use %edit (or %ed or ed) to open an editor, if you want to type in some complex code. Before you start Sage, make sure that the EDITOR environment variable is set to your favorite editor (by putting export EDITOR=/usr/bin/emacs or export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim or something similar in the appropriate place, like a .profile file).

I'm not that familiar with linux. What would that appropriate place be? I didn't find any .profile file in sage folder.

Thanks.

**edit**: I'm using ubuntu 10.04 if that is of any help.

Answer (score 1):

please try to find file `.bash_profile` or `.profile` in your home directory

Comment: I didn't find any such file. Maybe it has totally different name?

Comment: .profile is wrong anyway, it's not recommended to edit, also it's in /etc

Answer (score 1):

Put it into ".bashrc" in your home-directory.  If ".bashrc" doesn't exist, create a new one.
After editing ".bashrc", you must read it contents still into the actual shell. I.e. either restart it or "source ~/.bashrc"

Comment: I added "export EDITOR=/usr/bin/gedit" in .bashrc file and then restarted the system. I then ran sage and wrote %edit and it could not open editor. I'm thinking I would probably need to write something more in .bashrc but I have never done anything like this and I have no idea how to do it.